# How to extract name from html text that is covered by hyper link, using lxml Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I have been trying to use the lxml requests to take down just the names of players on this site http://mlb.mlb.com/news/probable_pitchers/. But from all of the other code that I have seen on the internet regarding how to use lxml, nothing that I have found has helped me. Anybody have some suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this site "HTML Scraping" http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Comment: First off thanks for the reply! And yes that site was actually one of the first ones I visited in my search, but the problem is is that while I understand why they used this: buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()'), I unfortunately do not understand what my equivalent would be to solely get the name out of this piece of html: <a href="http://mlb.mlb.com/team/player.jsp?player_id=608566">German Marquez</a>

Comment: For clarification the name I am looking to extract is "German Marquez"

Comment: Try this:                                                                                                  
        page = requests.get('http://mlb.mlb.com/news/probable_pitchers/')   
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        tree.xpath('//div/div/h5/a/text()')                                                                  Use the hierarchy as per the tags in your html.                                          I hope this will help you.